# Is there any option to share web pages content on google plus without using google plus iframe?

Tags: codeigniter, google-plus, share

I did the following code to in order to share the contents of my web pages.

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>


       </head>

        <body>
       <a class ="g-plusone" target="_blank" id="mybutton" data-callback="myCallback" href="<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"></a>
         </body>
         <script>
        gapi.plusone.render("g-plusone", { "callback": myCallback });
        function myCallback(jsonParam) {
      alert("URL: " + jsonParam.href + " state: " + jsonParam.state);
          }
       </script>
        </html>
```

But with this code i am not being able to share and get callback response. If i do this

```
        <body>
      <a target="_blank" id="mybutton" data-callback="myCallback" 
       href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com">Share on G+</a>
      </body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       gapi.plusone.render("mybutton", {"callback": myCallback});

        function myCallback(jsonParam) {
     alert("URL: " + jsonParam.href + " state: " + jsonParam.state);
       }
       </script>
```

I somehow become able to share the page but can't get callback. Can we use something other than google i-frame so that we can get success alert when the guest or anyone shares our web pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google+ does not support telling you when a user shares a post from your website.

[`gapi.plus.render`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#gapiplus_share_button) will render a share button but only supports `onstartinteraction` and `onendinteraction` which will tell you when the share button bubble is opened or closed. It will not tell you if a post is shared.

[`gapi.plusone.render`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#gapiplusone_1_button) supports the above two options plus a `callback` option. This will only tell you if the specific URL has been +1'd by the user or not. It will not tell you if the URL has been shared.